# Is it possible to make two texts blink in random timing using CSS3?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make two texts blink in a random timing? They should not blink together, but they should blink at a different phase. I tried to accomplish by using normal `text-decoration:blink`, but no use.. Then I tried using jQuery to fade in and fade out the text with some delay, but I'm hoping there would be some easy way of doing this in CSS3.

Comment: What do you mean by random? That the period keeps changing or only that the period is different between the texts? What have you tried?

Comment: "The period is different between the texts"..
I tried to accomplish by using normal text-decoration:blink, but no use.. then i tried using Jquery to fade in and fade out the text with some delay.. but i guess there would be some easy way of doing this in css3..

Comment: Are you sure you *want* to do that?

Comment: Blink has often been said to be *the* most annoying effect ever, which led to most browsers not even having blink support in CSS. You probably can't do it without JS or Flash. However, I'd suggest you don't do it at all. I'm having trouble fitting "blink" and "useful" in the same sentence.

Comment: It is useful to blink because it remove irritants from the surface of the cornea. There you go ;-)

Comment: Server-side blink implementation: http://cheese.blartwendo.com/web21-demo.html -- just run two of these with [coprime intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime) and the blinks won't line up very often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS `@keyframes` and `animation` for this. It wasn't totally clear from your question if you want different rates of blinking (the sample below), or the same rate, just not in sync. If you want the same rate out of sync, use `animation-delay` to start one of them after the other.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/SYGpy/

HTML:

```html
<div id="fast">fast</div>
<div id="regular">regular</div>
<div id="slow">slow</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#fast {
    animation:             blink 300ms linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:    blink 300ms linear infinite; 
        -webkit-animation: blink 300ms linear infinite; 
}

#regular {
    animation:             blink 750ms linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:    blink 750ms linear infinite; 
        -webkit-animation: blink 750ms linear infinite; 
}

#slow {
    animation:             blink 1500ms linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:    blink 1500ms linear infinite; 
        -webkit-animation: blink 1500ms linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes             blink { 0% {opacity:0;} 50% {opacity:1;} 100% {opacity:0;} }
    @-moz-keyframes    blink { 0% {opacity:0;} 50% {opacity:1;} 100% {opacity:0;} }
    @-webkit-keyframes blink { 0% {opacity:0;} 50% {opacity:1;} 100% {opacity:0;} }
```