# Could someone help me edit my first attempt at code for a blinking address replacement?

Tags: jquery

So, I'm totally new to this and trying to produce an effect where an old address blinks a few times, then some new text replaces it. However, the minute I use .replaceWith(), it overrides all the other .fade and the .append calls.

```
    <div id="footer-address">
<strong>Address</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; Old Address</div>

    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $( "#footer-address" ).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).replaceWith("We have moved! Our new address is").fadeOut(400).append("<strong>Address</strong>  New Address");
    });
    </script>
```

I appreciate you whacking me up side the head and offering the correct way to do something like this.

Thanks.

Comment: here are a few (more elegant) solutions for text blinking... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605698/text-blinking-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have a couple problems.

1. Your call to `replaceWith` is REPLACING the div, not changing the HTML inside of it, so once that fires, `#footer-address` no longer exists.
2. As pointed out earlier, not all functions get queued the same way.

An example that should work (tweak the numbers to get the effect you like):

```
$("#footer-address").fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400);

setTimeout(function() {
  $("#footer-address").html("We have moved! Our new address is").fadeOut(400);
}, 4400);

setTimeout(function() {
  $("#footer-address").html("<strong>Address</strong>  New Address").fadeIn(400);
}, 4800);
```

Demo at http://jsbin.com/uguhug/1/edit

Comment: Well, I don't have my 15 reputation yet otherwise I'd upvote this answer. Thank you for the instruction and demo. It worked on my site. 

I also appreciated the idea of using queue and dequeue, but for some reason those commands didn't seem to work on my Drupal 6.28 site. As a side note, I can't get .delay() to work either. Am I using the wrong library or something?

Answer (score 1):

`replaceWith` is different from the animation functions, which are queued and executed one after the other.

You can use [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2) to add non-animation functions to the animation queue:

```
$( "#footer-address" )
    .fadeOut(400)
    .fadeIn(400)
    .fadeOut(400)
    .queue(function(){
         $( "#footer-address" ).empty().append("We have moved! Our new address is");
         $(this).dequeue();
     })
    .fadeOut(400)
    .queue(function(){
         $( "#footer-address" ).append("<strong>Address</strong>  New Address");
         $(this).dequeue();
     })
```

Dont' forget the [`dequeue`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) call to indicate that the "animation" has finished and the next one should begin.

---

Original suggestion:

You could use a callback function to wait for the animations to finish before replacing the element:

```
$( "#footer-address" ).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400, function(){
    $( "#footer-address" ).replaceWith("We have moved! Our new address is").fadeOut(400,      function(){
        $( "#footer-address" ).append("<strong>Address</strong>  New Address");
    })
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about the .queue. Much more elegant than my external `setTimeout()` calls. However, it's still going to break, because `replaceWith` is going to remove `#footer-address`.

Comment: @DavidKiger You're right, thanks for pointing that out. Used `.empty().append()` instead.

Comment: Hi guys, for some reason my Drupal 6.28 site could not read the .queue command. It halted after the 2nd fadeOut(400). I have also had trouble using .delay() on my site. Any ideas as to why? According to my settings I'm using minified JQuery UI 1.7 and jQuery Update 1.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CSS3 animations (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623507/551093)):

```
#footer-address.blink {
    animation:         blink 300ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:    blink 300ms linear infinite; 
    -webkit-animation: blink 300ms linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes         blink { 0% {opacity:0;} 50% {opacity:1;} 100% {opacity:0;} }
@-moz-keyframes    blink { 0% {opacity:0;} 50% {opacity:1;} 100% {opacity:0;} }
@-webkit-keyframes blink { 0% {opacity:0;} 50% {opacity:1;} 100% {opacity:0;} }
```

Make sure the `#footer-address` element has the .blink class to start off with, then after a certain duration, remove it using js.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#footer-address').removeClass('blink').text('We have moved! Our new address is...');
}, 4000);
```